# Split words with a capital letter in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know how to split words starting with capital letters from a string?

Example:

```
    DECLARE @var1 varchar(100) = 'OneTwoThreeFour'
    DECLARE @var2 varchar(100) = 'OneTwoThreeFourFive'
    DECLARE @var3 varchar(100) = 'One'

    SELECT @var1 as Col1, <?> as Col2
    SELECT @var2 as Col1, <?> as Col2
    SELECT @var3 as Col1, <?> as Col2
```

expected result:

```
    Col1                Col2
    OneTwoThreeFour     One Two three Four
    OneTwoThreeFourFive One Two Three Four Five
    One                 One
```

If this is not possible (or if too long) an scalar function would be okay as well.

Comment: I suppose It can be done by using a regex to find (A-Z) and replace by "space"+ (A-Z). Note scalar functions can be performance hogs.

Comment: @jean There's no regex in SQL Server.

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) outlines a method to add simple regex support to t-sql. Performance caveats apply. Note that you can use simple patterns in the argument to the `like` operator, ie. `%[a-z][A-Z]%`, to identify records that have columns with camel case data.

Comment: By regex I mean to do anything like SELECT patindex('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%','gaurang Ahmedabad' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a function I created that is similar to the "removing non-alphabetic characters".  [How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server/1008566#1008566)

This one uses a case sensitive collation which actively seeks out a non-space/capital letter combination and then uses the STUFF function to insert the space.  This IS a scalar UDF, so some folks will immediately say that it will be slower than other solutions.  To that notion, I say, please test it.  This function does not use any table data and only loops as many times as necessary, so it will likely give you very good performance.

```
Create Function dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case(@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^ ][A-Z]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) + 1, 0, ' ')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Call it like this:

```
Select dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case('OneTwoThreeFour')
Select dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case('OneTwoThreeFour')
Select dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case('One')
Select dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case('OneTwoThree')
Select dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case('stackOverFlow')
Select dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case('StackOverFlow')
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But only if you have 1 uppercase letter.
Like "EmailTitle" becomes "Email Title" Which is perfect.    
But what about if you have more than 1 uppercase letter per word.
"EmailGUID" becomes "Email G U I D". Whereas I want "Email GUID"

Replace the @KeepValues with:
`Set @KeepValues = '%[^ A-Z][A-Z]%'`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function I have just created.

**FUNCTION**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case
 (
     @String VARCHAR(4000)
 )
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Char CHAR(1);
DECLARE @i    INT = 0;
DECLARE @OutString VARCHAR(4000) = '';


WHILE (@i <= LEN(@String))
BEGIN
    SELECT @Char = SUBSTRING(@String, @i,1)

    IF (@Char = UPPER(@Char) Collate Latin1_General_CS_AI) 
       SET @OutString = @OutString + ' ' + @Char;
    ELSE 
       SET @OutString = @OutString +  @Char;

     SET @i += 1;
END

 SET @OutString =  LTRIM(@OutString);

 RETURN @OutString;

END
```

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Strings VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @TABLE 
VALUES ('OneTwoThree')   ,
       ('FourFiveSix')   ,
       ('SevenEightNine')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case(Strings) AS Vals
FROM @TABLE
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════════════╗
║       Vals       ║
╠══════════════════╣
║ One Two Three    ║
║ Four Five Six    ║
║ Seven Eight Nine ║
╚══════════════════╝
```

Comment: seems ineffective. You are looping through the varchar splitting it and putting it together again character by character. Not good for performance.

Answer (score 4):

If a single query is needed 26 REPLACE can be used to check every upper case letter like

```
SELECT @var1 col1, REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(
                      ...
                       REPLACE(@var1, 'A', ' A')
                    , ... 
                  , 'X', ' X')
                , 'Y', ' Y')
              , 'Z', ' Z') col2
```

Not the most beautiful thing but it'll work.

**EDIT**
Just to add another function to do the same thing in a different way of the other answers

```
CREATE FUNCTION splitCapital (@param Varchar(MAX))
RETURNS Varchar(MAX)
BEGIN
  Declare @ret Varchar(MAX) = '';
  declare @len int = len(@param);

  WITH Base10(N) AS (
              SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 
    UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ), Chars(N) As (
    Select TOP(@len)
           nthChar 
         = substring(@param, u.N + t.N*10 + h.N*100 + th.N*1000 + 1, 1) 
           Collate Latin1_General_CS_AI
    FROM   Base10 u
           CROSS JOIN Base10 t
           CROSS JOIN Base10 h
           CROSS JOIN Base10 th
    WHERE  u.N + t.N*10 + h.N*100 + th.N*1000 < @len
    ORDER BY u.N + t.N*10 + h.N*100 + th.N*1000
  )
  SELECT @ret += Case nthChar 
                      When UPPER(nthChar) Then ' ' 
                      Else '' 
                 End + nthChar
  FROM   Chars

  RETURN @ret;
END
```

This one uses the possibility of TSQL to concatenate string variable, I had to use the TOP N trick to force the Chars CTE rows in the right order

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Select replace('bBb' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'B', ' B') returns 'b Bb'

Comment: Sure did not deserve a down vote.  +1 to get you even.

Comment: @blam when an answer gives the wrong result, it deserves a downvote

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Really you did not get that a case sensitive collation was required.

Answer (score 2):

Build a Numbers table.  There are some excellent posts on SO to show you how to do this.  Populate it with values up the maximum length of your input string.  Select the values from 1 through the actual length of the current input string.  Cross join this list of numbers to the input string.  Use the result to `SUBSTRING()` each character.  Then you can *either* compare the resulting list of one-charachter values to a pre-populated table-valued variable *or* convert each character to an integer using `ASCII()` and choose only those between 65 ('A') and 90 ('Z').  At this point you have a list which is the position of each upper-case character in your input string.  `UNION` the maximum length of your input string onto the end of this list.  You'll see why in just a second.  Now you can `SUBSTRING()` your input variable, starting at the Number given by row N and taking a length of (the Number given by row N+1) - (The number given by row N).  This is why you have to `UNION` the extra Number on the end.  Finally concatenate all these substring together, space-separated, using the algorithm of your choice.

Sorry, don't have an instance in front of me to try out code.  Sounds like a fun task.  I think doing it with nested `SELECT` statements will get convoluted and un-maintainable; better to lay it out as CTEs, IMHO.

Comment: Yes it was fun creating this I have just created one have a look :)

Comment: @M.Ali - I was admiring your answer just now.  My suggestion to the OP was that he try it as a single SELECT, leveraging the relational characteristics of the query engine and minimising any performance impact of the `CROSS APPLY` which a function-based solution may incur.

Answer (score 1):

I know that there are already some good answers out there, but if you wanted to avoid creating a function, you could also use a recursive CTE to accomplish this. It's certainly not a clean way of doing this, but it works.

```
DECLARE
    @camelcase nvarchar(4000) = 'ThisIsCamelCased'
;

WITH
    split
AS
    (
        SELECT
              [iteration]   = 0
             ,[string]      = @camelcase

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
             [iteration]    = split.[iteration] + 1
            ,[string]       = STUFF(split.[string], pattern.[index] + 1, 0, ' ')
        FROM
            split
        CROSS APPLY
            ( SELECT [index] = PATINDEX(N'%[^ ][A-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin, split.[string]) )
            pattern
        WHERE
            pattern.[index] > 0
    )
SELECT TOP (1)
    [spaced] = split.[string]
FROM
    split
ORDER BY
    split.[iteration]   DESC
;
```

As I said, this isn't a pretty way to write a query, but I use things like this when I'm just writing up some ad-hoc queries where I would not want to add new artifacts to the database. You could also use this to create your function as an inline table valued function, which is always a tad nicer.

Comment: I wrote out a solution for another thread that got directed here, I was going to post it anyway, but it looks like you had the same idea. Nice use of functions, too. I learned something here today.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
    declare  @t nvarchar (100) ='IamTheTestString'  
    declare  @len int
    declare  @Counter int =0 
    declare  @Final nvarchar (100) =''
    set @len =len( @t)


    while (@Counter <= @len)
    begin 

    set @Final= @Final + Case when  ascii(substring (@t,@Counter,1))>=65 and  
    ascii(substring (@t,@Counter,1))<=90 then ' '+substring (@t,@Counter,1) else 
    substring (@t,@Counter,1) end


    set @Counter=@Counter+1
    end

    print ltrim(@Final)
```

Comment: ` declare  @t nvarchar (100) ='IamTheTestSTRING'  
    declare  @len int
    declare  @Counter int =0 
    declare  @Final nvarchar (100) =''
    set @len =len( @t)
    declare @prevUpper bit = 0


    while (@Counter <= @len)
     begin 
   if ascii(substring (@t,@Counter,1))>=65 and ascii(substring (@t,@Counter,1))<=90       
       BEGIN
        if @prevUpper = 0 
      set @Final += ' '
     set @prevUpper = 1 
       end
      else
    set @prevUpper = 0 
     set @Final += substring (@t,@Counter,1)       
     set @Counter += 1
 end

    print ltrim(@Final)`

Comment: The previous wouldn't go funky over consecutive upper case letters