# Split words with a capital letter in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have sene [Split words with a capital letter in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470794/split-words-with-a-capital-letter-in-sql) which is applicable to MS SQL but I was wondering how to achieve the same using PostgreSQL

Basically I'm getting values such as `FirstNameValue` but I need it to be `First Name Value`

Unfortunately I don't know where to even start. I got to the following and got stuck straight away

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ThoMasTest', '[^ ][A-Z].', ' ')
```

The result from a string such as `ThoMasTest` should be `Tho Mas Test`

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select regexp_replace('ThoMasTest', '([a-z])([A-Z])', '\1 \2','g');
```

The expression matches two characters next to eachother, each one in its own group:

1. `[a-z]` that matches a lowercase letter.
2. `[A-Z]` finds a capital letter

So if one lowercase if immediately followed by a capital letter insert a space between them.

Do that globally `'g'`.

Comment: I get the following result "Th a est" but the result features an odd character in the position of the space...

Comment: The 3:rd argument needs to be `\1 \2` not `' '`! Or if you have that, put in one extra backslash to make it `'\\1 \\2'`, that could solve it if you are using some strange terminal.

Comment: select regexp_replace('JanuszJasinski', '([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1 \\2','g'); worked