# Split by uppercase Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am loooking for a regex expression or something that from this :

```
------------------------
| id  |   prop_name    |
------------------------
|  1  |  isThisAnExample |
------------------------
```

To this :

```
-----------------------------
| id  |   prop_name         |
-----------------------------
|  1  |  Is This An Example |
-----------------------------
```

Of course it would be cool if the first character is uppercase and also if the other words start with lowercase. But only spliting them also will be okay.

Comment: You will find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470794/split-words-with-a-capital-letter-in-sql

Comment: @Marc That's not Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is the regexp you are looking for

"Insert a blank between each lower case character followed by an upper case character":

```
select regexp_replace('IsThisAnExample', '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])', '\1 \2') from dual
```

First character can simply replaced by an upper case letter by

```
select upper(substr('isThisAn Example', 1,1))||substr('isThisAn Example', 2) from dual;
```

So, first replace the first character and regexp_replace for the result:

```
select regexp_replace(upper(substr('isThisAn Example', 1,1))||substr('isThisAn Example', 2), '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])', '\1 \2') from dual;
```

If only the first character of your sentence should be an upper case letter, then try:

```
select upper(substr(regexp_replace('IsThisAnExample', '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])', '\1 \2'),1,1))||
       lower(substr(regexp_replace('IsThisAnExample', '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])', '\1 \2'),2))
 from dual
```

Comment: Great. Now if you can extend your solution to : "Insert a blank between each lower case character followed by an upper case character and make those lower case characters upper and also the first character of the row" will be everything I am looking for

Comment: Yes we now have upper first char which is great ! 'isThisAnExample' --> 'Is This An Example'. Now the last request is from 'Is This An Example' --> 'Is this an example'.

Comment: Use initcap(lower('Is This An Example')).

Comment: @nilsman initcap capitalizes each word, this is not what lazarov asked for. See my changes

Answer (score 0):

Better use regex, but anyway:

```
SELECT listagg(splitted, '') within GROUP (ORDER BY lvl) FROM( 
    SELECT LEVEL lvl, CASE WHEN SUBSTR(your_string, LEVEL, 1) = 
                    UPPER(SUBSTR(your_string, LEVEL, 1)) 
        THEN ' ' || SUBSTR(your_string, LEVEL, 1) ELSE 
                    SUBSTR(your_string, LEVEL, 1)  END splitted
FROM (SELECT 'isThisAnExample' your_string FROM dual) 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(your_string) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Frank's solution, but simpler (reducing the use of regular expressions as much as possible):

```
with
     input ( str ) as (
       select 'isThisAnExample' from dual
     )
select upper(substr(str, 1, 1)) ||
       lower(regexp_replace(substr(str, 2), '(^|[[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])', '\1 \2'))
          as modified_str
from   input;

MODIFIED_STR
------------------
Is this an example

1 row selected.
```